# creation and last modified date of and system.drawing.image

Tags: c#, image, hash

I'm working on a project and I need to create a hash for and image and I did it, with the image propertyItems, but if I copy paste the image I get the same hash, I thought on get the hash based on the creation and last modified date.

I did some research and I found that I get use File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Users\image.png");
and File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Users\image.png");  but that implies that i have a path to the files, and my file is being download from a blob storage, is there any better way to do it? instead of needing to downloading and saving every image in a folder to get the path.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: What kind of ‘blob storage’ are you using and how are you accessing the blob?

Comment: Also if you download the image to a file, the creation and modified dates of the file will both be the download time, not the content creation and modified time.

Comment: Im downloading an image from the blob storage, and then i generate another image based on html (that contains that blob image) and i get a byte[]

Comment: @stuartd This is because i want to make an unique image and to do so, my ideia was to take the creation and modified date, and then generate an hash based on that and a few other properties, so if anyone download the image, it will get a diferent creation and modified date, but i cant find the right way to do it

Comment: Does the blob storage you’re using allow you to store metadata along with the file data? That might be one way.